# OpenCV: crop image with gaussian blur

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, gaussian

I have an grayscale image, and I want to crop a rectangle of size `w x h` centered at pixel `(x,y)`. The problem is, I don't want the crop to look boxy so around the edge I want to gaussian blur the values so that they smoothly transisition to zero. Any ideas on how to do this?

Currently I am doing:

```
int bb_min_x = center_x - width/2.0;
int bb_max_x = center_x + width/2.0;

int bb_min_y = center_y - height/2.0;
int bb_max_y = center_y + height/2.0;

for(int y = bb_min_y; y <= bb_max_y; y++){
    for(int x = bb_min_x; x <= bb_max_x; x++){
        final_img.at<uchar>(y,x) = original_img.at<uchar>(y,x);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does "gaussian blur the values" mean? your description sounds like a simple fade out. blurring is something different and the croped blurred result also will look "boxy".

Comment: @vlad_tepesch I think you are right, a fade out is what I'm after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this function:

compute the distance from your input rectangle and use that as a fading factor.

```
cv::Mat cropFade(cv::Mat _img, cv::Rect _roi, int _maxFadeDistance)
{
cv::Mat fadeMask = cv::Mat::ones(_img.size(), CV_8UC1);
cv::rectangle(fadeMask, _roi, cv::Scalar(0),-1);

cv::imshow("mask",fadeMask>0);

cv::Mat dt;
cv::distanceTransform(fadeMask > 0, dt, CV_DIST_L2 ,CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE);



// fade to a maximum distance:
double maxFadeDist;

if(_maxFadeDistance > 0)
    maxFadeDist = _maxFadeDistance;
else
{
    // find min/max vals
    double min,max;
    cv::minMaxLoc(dt,&min,&max);
    maxFadeDist = max;
}


//dt = 1.0-(dt* 1.0/max);   // values between 0 and 1 since min val should alwaysbe 0
dt = 1.0-(dt* 1.0/maxFadeDist); // values between 0 and 1 in fading region

cv::imshow("blending mask", dt);


cv::Mat imgF;
_img.convertTo(imgF,CV_32FC3);


std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
cv::split(imgF,channels);
// multiply pixel value with the quality weights for image 1
for(unsigned int i=0; i<channels.size(); ++i)
    channels[i] = channels[i].mul(dt);

cv::Mat outF;
cv::merge(channels,outF);

cv::Mat out;
outF.convertTo(out,CV_8UC3);



return out;
}
```

calling that with `cv::Mat out = cropFade(in, cv::Rect(in.cols/4, in.rows/4, in.cols/2, in.rows/2), in.cols/8);` gives me those results for a lena with the specified rect:

[image]

[image]

this is the result for full image fading from the same unchanged rect:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach:

```
// Create a weight image
int border=25;
cv::Mat_<float> rect=cv::Mat_<float>::zeros(height,width)
cv::rectangle(rect,cv::Rect(border/2,border/2,width-border,height-border),cv::Scalar(1),-1);
cv::Mat_<float> weights, kernel=cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE,cv::Size(border,border));
int nnz = cv::countNonZero(kernel);
cv::filter2D(rect,weights,-1,kernel/nnz);
```

This creates a weight image like the following:

[image]

Then you use it to fade your image out:

```
for(int y = bb_min_y; y <= bb_max_y; y++){
    for(int x = bb_min_x; x <= bb_max_x; x++){
        float w = weights.at<float>(y-bb_min_y,x-bb_min_x);
        uchar val = original_img.at<uchar>(y,x);
        final_img.at<uchar>(y,x) = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(w*val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you turn your bounding box into a contour you can use [pointPolygonTest](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#pointpolygontest) to calculate the distance to the edge of the bounding box for each pixel. If you then lower the color values to zero depending on this distance you get a blur effect.

See [this page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/point_polygon_test/point_polygon_test.html) for an example.